# What is yarn.lock and expo in react native?

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I am new in React native development. I didn't find what Yarn is for and how it works in React native.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yarn is dependency management software, that means if u need any third party library for ur react native app like networking library or new component, then u can install it using yarn, and expo on the other hand is client for the react native bundler server, it can run the app on ur device while developing.you can Install expo from play store or app store